# I want to remove staight line that shows in my blog page. It is only shows in firefox not in the chrome

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to remove staight line that shows in my blog page. It is only shows in firefox not in the chrome. I don't know why it is showing in firefox?

I have added :

[My website link](http://www.veepal.com/blog/)

Comment: Can you add screenshots for both?

Comment: it is showing in FF as well , that is just article boundary, which you can change in css

Comment: Yes, it is showing in FF only not in the chrome

Comment: I have added screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove width:1px in `style.css line No: 5149`

```
#main-content .container::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    content: "";
}
```